# Mobile apps integration with facebook

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

I have created a mobile game using phone gap. In that game, the user has the option to invite Facebook friends - and I have gotten to the point where I have successfully debugged my FB API and JavaScript - and gotten it to work on my Apache web server.

However, when I integrate the code into my phone gap game, the execution results in the following error:

> Error: I/Web Console(684): Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. at https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=Myapp_id&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&display=none&domain=&origin=2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D17%23cb%3Df1f21b8b6%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252Ff51b7ec1c%26domain%3D%26relation%3Dparent&sdk=joey:1

I'm wondering:

1. If this has to do with the Facebook Apps settings and the URL I have set for my mobile app, or
2. The Redirect URL I have to enter for mobile related apps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set up domain white list approprietly, [look](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide).
To get oauth 2 token from user, open ChildBrowser with facebook auth page and parse url.
Update for comment.
It seems like problem with facebook app settings. Please, check your redirect url, I set https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html and then I checked this url in webview.

Comment: I have analyzed whitelist and I implemented child browser concept in my app while loading URL in child Browser same Previous error only came..  Error: I/Web Console(684): Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. at https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=Myapp_id&response .....   Anytink I'm missing in facebook app settings or config.xml ?